# How can I position the histograms vertically

Tags: r

I am new to R and my professor asked me to position the histograms vertically. I am required to use only  `ggplot2`. Here is my code:

```r
(ggplot(data=shippingData, aes(Days)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1,col="gray", 
                 fill="steelblue", 
                 alpha = 1)  +
  labs(title="Delivery Times(in Days) by Center") +
  labs(x="Days)", y="Count") + facet_grid(facets=. ~ Center))
```

Output is positioned as horizontally like this :

[image: My output]

But it is supposed to look like this:

[image: Wanted output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try `facet_grid(rows = vars(Center)`.

If you want to use `facet_wrap` to get the labels on top, try this:

`facet_wrap(~Center, nrow = 3)`.

Comment: This worked for me thanks but I want to get strip labes on the top of each histogram (right now strip labes are on right side of the histograms). As far as i know I can only do it with facet_wrap. I have no idea how to change the position of those strip labes to the top of the histograms.

Comment: You are the best <3

Answer (score 2):

Try `facet_grid(facets=Center ~ .)` **or** `facet_wrap(~Center, ncol=1)`

Comment: It says its an "unused argument (ncol = 1)"

Comment: I dont know if its going to make a difference but i did a typo. Its ggplot2 not ggplot.